# Building my own LPARAM variable

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to create my own LPARAM to pass to the win32 function GetKeyNameText(), (the first parameter takes a LPARAM var).

This may seem like doing things the hard way, but its a work around for not having specific amounts of information & also working at the bit level is REALLY confusing to me which is why I want to familiarise myself with this.

So what I want to put in my LPARAM var is:
- set the 16-23 bits to the keyboard Scan code: I've got the scan code I just dont know how I would combine it into a 32bit variable?
- set the 24th bit to the extended-key flag (I have no idea how to get this yet alone how to combine it into a 32 bit variable)
- set the 25th bit to the dont care bit to I do care - so would I set this bit to 1?

So I understand the way binary & bits work...I think, its amazing I understand higher lvl concepts like polymorphism but not lower lvl computer hardware stuff :P

So I have a 32 bit(or byte?) variable, does that mean I have 32 0's & 1's: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
OR
I have a variable like this XXXXXX, eg 100011(which is 35), where the last number is 2^0(so 1), then 2^1(2), then 2^2(4), .... then finally 2^5(32).

So to create my LPARAM would I do this:

```
DWORD scanCode = 0x??;  // a DWORD is a 32bit var, but the scan code is only 7 bits long?
bit   extFlag       = 1;        // now is there a bit variable? How can I find out the extended-key flag also?
bit   careBit       = 1;       

//Now to combine it all would I do this? 
DWORD myLParam = scanCode & extFlag & careBit;
// OR
LPARAM myLParam = scanCode & extFlag & careBit;
```

Comment: You may want to read a bit more about bit shifting, bitwise operators, etc. This is fundamental stuff you'll need very often, when programming.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to use bitfields ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx )

Heres a structure i use to get key state from a LPARAM:

```
union KeyState
{
    LPARAM lparam;

    struct
    {
        unsigned nRepeatCount : 16;
        unsigned nScanCode : 8;
        unsigned nExtended : 1;
        unsigned nReserved : 4;
        unsigned nContext : 1;
        unsigned nPrev : 1;
        unsigned nTrans : 1;
    };
};
```

Then you would implement it simply as:

```
KeyState keyState; // declared globally
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
    keyState.lparam = lparam;

    // Use values here, e.g:
    printf("%d,%d,%d", keyState.nRepeatCount, keyState.nScanCode, keyState.nExtended);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find this much more readable than using any number of bit shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char keyName[100];
int scanCode   = ????;
bool extended  = ????;
bool dontcare  = ????;

int retval = GetKeyNameText(
    (scanCode & 0xFF) << 16 | (LPARAM)extended << 24 | (LPARAM)dontcare << 25,
    keyName, sizeof(keyName));
printf("%s\n", keyName);
```

Now you'll have to decide (you can experiment, or read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) which values you want to give to scanCode, extended and dontcare.