# Inspecting the LPARAM on WM_KEYDOWN - incorrect values?

Tags: c++, winapi, bit

I have some simple code that inspects the LPARAM variable(sent to the main WNDPROC) values(bits) when the WM_KEYDOWN is received.

**But I am getting some funny values int there:** In MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx, it says that the last bit(of LPARAM) should always be 0 for a keydown message but when I output the LPARAM value its ALWAYS 1? Also the scan code only ever alters between 5(when I press an arrow or windows key) or zero for normal letters & numbers - shouldn't they change according to the key thats pressed?

Lastly if I hold down the shift key for a while, shouldn't the repeat count go up? When I do this the repeat count stays at zero?

**Is my code for inspecting LPARAM values wrong or maybe my whole message pump?**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            outputLParam( lParam );
            outputLParamDefault( lParam );
            //printf("A: %d, %d, %d\n", lParam & 0x30, lParam & 0x31, lParam & 0x32 );
            //printf("\n");
        }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default: 
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void outputLParam( LPARAM lParam )
{
    printf("Repeat Count        : %d\n", (lParam >> 0x01) & ((1<<15)-1));  // print the value of the 1st 15 bits
    printf("Scan Code           : %d\n", (lParam >> 0x16) & ((1<<7)-1));   // print the value of the next 7 bits
    printf("Extended Key        : %d\n", lParam & 0x24);                   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Reserved            : %d\n", (lParam >> 0x25) & ((1<<3)-1));   // print the value of the next 3 bits
    printf("Context             : %d\n", lParam & 0x29);                   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Prev Key State      : %d\n", lParam & 0x30);                   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Transition Key State: %d\n", lParam & 0x31);                   // print the value of the next bit
}

void outputLParamDefault( LPARAM lParam )
{
    printf("LPARAM: ");

    for ( int i=0x01, j=0; j<32; j++, i++)
    {
        printf("%d", lParam & i);
    } 

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code for inspecting the bits is wrong, *and* the bitgroups stated in the comments are wrong.

E.g. the docs say that the lower 16 bits are the repeat count.

You get that by

```
(lParam >> 0) & ((1L << 16) - 1)
```

in the "system" that apparently your code uses.

In contrast, your code has the incorrect expression `(lParam >> 0x01) & ((1<<15)-1))`.

The scan code is then the next 8 bits, not 7 bits.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

All your mask counts are wrong and the repeat count offset is wrong. The repeat count starts at bit 0 (not bit 1) so doesn't need to be shifted, and your mask then misses off the top bit.

Answer (score 0):

A [question I answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954571/breaking-up-a-lparam-variable-looking-at-groups-of-bits/6963047#6963047) is relevant to your situation. Create a custom structure instead of creating a mess with bit-shifting.