# Is this LPARAM separated correctly now?

Tags: c++, winapi, bit-manipulation

I am examining the value of a LPARAM when I receive the WM_KEYDOWN event. But I am unsure that I am correctly examining the 1st 16 bits then the next 8 bits & so on. This is how MSDN explains a LPARAM is organised for a WM_KEYDOWN msg:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx

Are my bit (splits?) correct?:

```
void outputLParam( LPARAM lParam )
{
    printf("Repeat Count        : %d\n", (lParam) & ((1L<<16)-1));          // print the value of the 1st 16 bits
    printf("Scan Code           : %d\n", (lParam >> 0x16) & ((1L<<8)-1));   // print the value of the next 8 bits
    printf("Extended Key        : %d\n", lParam & 0x24);                    // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Reserved            : %d\n", (lParam >> 0x25) & ((1L<<4)-1));   // print the value of the next 4 bits
    printf("Context             : %d\n", lParam & 0x29);                    // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Prev Key State      : %d\n", lParam & 0x30);                    // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Transition Key State: %d\n", lParam & 0x31);                    // print the value of the next bit
}
```

Comment: This really should have been a follow up/continuation to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993957/inspecting-the-lparam-on-wm-keydown-incorrect-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
void outputLParam( LPARAM lParam )
{
    printf("Repeat Count        : %d\n", (lParam) & 0xFFFF);      // print the value of the 1st 16 bits
    printf("Scan Code           : %d\n", (lParam >> 16) & 0xFF);  // print the value of the next 8 bits
    printf("Extended Key        : %d\n", (lParam >> 24) & 0x1);   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Reserved            : %d\n", (lParam >> 25) & 0xF));  // print the value of the next 4 bits
    printf("Context             : %d\n", (lParam >> 29) & 0x1);   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Prev Key State      : %d\n", (lParam >> 30) & 0x1);   // print the value of the next bit
    printf("Transition Key State: %d\n", (lParam >> 31) & 0x1);   // print the value of the next bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993957/inspecting-the-lparam-on-wm-keydown-incorrect-values), you should really be [declaring your own custom structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954571/breaking-up-a-lparam-variable-looking-at-groups-of-bits/6963047#6963047). It's far more coherent and less error-prone. It simply makes more sense for this particular situation and takes full advantage of the language's constructs. There is no need for any bit-arithmetic to be done here.

EDIT: That said, Anton's solution *is* correct.

Comment: Why the downvote? You'd rather see `(lParam) & 0xFFFF` than `KeyInfo.nRepeatCount`?